# How can I implement a nested representation using intermediate model?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am quite new to Django and Django Rest Framework.

What I like to do in my project is display intermediate model's information using `ListAPIView` and also include detailed information about another Model connected to the intermediate model with a Foreign Key Relationship in the form of nested representation.

I have 3 models in my project, `User`, `Content`, `Bookmark`.

My model goes like below.

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    facebook_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    is_facebook = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Content(models.Model):
    seq = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    place = models.TextField(null=True)
    realm_name = models.TextField(null=True)
    area = models.TextField(null=True)
    price = models.TextField(null=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True)
    ticket_url = models.TextField(null=True)
    phone = models.TextField(null=True)
    thumbnail = models.TextField(null=True)

    bookmarks = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='Bookmark')
```

The last model, an intermediate model to connect `MyUser` and `Content`.

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'content'),)
        ordering = ['-created_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} bookmarked by user {}'.format(self.content, self.user)
```

I want to use `BookmarkListAPIView` to show certain user's bookmark information and some detailed information of Contents that the user added such as `title`, `price`, and `start_date`.

Below is my Serializer and `ListAPIView`.

```
class BookmarkListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Bookmark.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookmarkSerializer
    pagination_class = DefaultResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return user.bookmark_set.all().order_by('-created_date')

class BookmarkedContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = ('title', 'start_date', 'price')


class BookmarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    content = BookmarkedContentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    #bookmark = BookmarkedContentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Bookmark
        fields = ('content', 'user')
```

Currently, the API gives me results just like below.

> {
>     "count": 6,
>     "next": null,
>     "previous": null,
>     "results": [
>       {
>         "content": 8,
>         "user": 4
>       },
>       {
>         "content": 6,
>         "user": 4
>       },
>       {
>         "content": 1,
>         "user": 4
>       },
>       {
>         "content": 2,
>         "user": 4
>       },
>       {
>         "content": 3,
>         "user": 4
>       },
>       {
>         "content": 10,
>         "user": 4
>       }
>     ]
>   }

As mentioned above, I want to use the content ID to fetch more detailed information about each bookmark instance.

It will look like

```
{
  "count": 6,
  "next": null,
  "previous": null,
  "results": [
   { "content_id": 4
      "title": A,
      "price": 10$, 
      "user": 4
    },
   {
      "content_id": 6,
      "title": B, 
      "price": 13$,
      "user": 4
    },
   {
      "content_id": 1,
      "title": C, 
      "price": 4$, 
      "user": 4
    },
   ]
}
```

I tried many things written in the DRF doc but was not able to find any materials related to my situation.

If you have any idea, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key you're missing is the `source` keyword argument for each field. Here's some docs on it for you: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source

And I believe this implementation should work for you or at least be very close:

```
class BookmarkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    content_id = serializers.IntegerField(source='content.id')
    title = serializers.CharField(source='content.title')
    price = serializers.CharField(source='content.price')
    user = serializers.IntegerField(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Bookmark
        fields = ('content_id', 'user', title', 'price')
```

Comment: Thank you! As I took a look at it, I just got to know that it was quite a simple matter.. but still thank you for your advice! Now it works perfectly!